# How does the following motion [[ apply?

Tags: python, vim

I'm trying to get a hang of how `[[` and `]]` works. According to the docs, it goes to the next/prev **section**:

> A section begins after a form-feed () in the first column and at each of
>   a set of section macros, specified by the pairs of characters in the
>   'sections' option.  The default is "SHNHH HUnhsh", which defines a section to
>   start at the nroff macros ".SH", ".NH", ".H", ".HU", ".nh" and ".sh".

I'm not really sure what that means, but in practice, it seems to go to any `def` or `class` that starts in column 1. Is that more-or-less how it works? Let's say I have functions as follows:

```
class MyClass

    def mydef1

    def mydef2

    def mydef3

    ...etc
```

Is there a way to jump between all the defs? Most functions will have line breaks for readability so doing something like `}` or `{` doesn't work too well here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Sections" originally come from troff/nroff, and as such they are not particularly useful nowadays. Many filetype-plugins, including ft-python, remap "sections" to do something more reasonable. An exact definition should be searched by reading the docs or browsing the source code, but for python it looks like "class or def at the beginning of line".

> Is there a way to jump between all the defs?

I suppose you want `]m` and `[m`. Hint: you can enter `:map <buffer>` to see buffer-local mappings currently in effect.